# crontab and selinux

Tags: cron, selinux, drupal

I have Drupal 7 on RHEL 7 and it looks like SELinux blocks crontab.
`aureport -a` showes

`90. 11/27/2015 01:32:35 httpd system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 87 file unlink system_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0 denied 10061
91. 11/27/2015 01:42:35 httpd system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 87 file unlink system_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0 denied 10062
92. 11/27/2015 01:52:43 httpd system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 87 file unlink system_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0 denied 10063
93. 11/27/2015 02:02:48 httpd system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 87 file unlink system_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0 denied 10069
94. 11/27/2015 02:13:02 httpd system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 87 file unlink system_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0 denied 10081
95. 11/27/2015 02:23:02 httpd system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 87 file unlink system_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0 denied 10082
96. 11/27/2015 02:33:03 httpd system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 87 file unlink system_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0 denied 10083
97. 11/27/2015 02:43:03 httpd system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 87 file unlink system_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0 denied 10084
98. 11/27/2015 02:53:09 httpd system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 87 file unlink system_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0 denied 10094`

Looks like it is the same 10 minutes period when Drupal Ultimate cron try to start.
I am pretty sure the problem with SELinux, but I cant find any understandable solution.

Comment: What user is your cronjob running as? It seems to try to delete (for rotation) some httpd logfiles?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is not talking about `crontab`, but `httpd` (Apache).

Start investigating by temporarily turning SELinux off:

```
setenforce 0
```

(which will address *most* but not *all* of the blockage).  The problem can usually be *fixed* using one of the SELinux settings via `semanage` (if Drupal's files are stored in some place that SELinux does not expect), or using `restorecon` (to repair the meta information for the filesystem).

As a last resort, you could use [audit2allow](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Fixing_Problems-Allowing_Access_audit2allow.html).

For reference:

- [Common SELinux Configuration for Apache](https://drupalwatchdog.com/volume-2/issue-2/using-apache-and-selinux-together)  (see for instance the use of `semanage`)
- [SELinux User's and Administrator's Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html-single/SELinux_Users_and_Administrators_Guide/index.html)
- [An Introduction to SELinux on CentOS 7 – Part 2: Files and Processes](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-selinux-on-centos-7-part-2-files-and-processes)
- [13.1. The Apache HTTP Server and SELinux](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/22/html/SELinux_Users_and_Administrators_Guide/chap-Managing_Confined_Services-The_Apache_HTTP_Server.html)